# Changing the steepness of a parametric equation

Tags: 3d, geometry, octave, differential-equations, parametric-equations

I have a working Octave script the creates a spiral

Script:

```
clc
close all
clear all

u=linspace(0,4*pi,100);
v=linspace(0,pi,100);
[u,v]=meshgrid(u,v);
x=u.*sin(u).*cos(v);
y=u.*cos(u).*cos(v);
z=-u.*sin(v) .-  sin(60/180 * pi)*(sqrt((x).^2 + (y).^2));
figure(1)
mesh(x,y,z);
view([-57,32])
h=gca; 
get(h,'FontSize') 
set(h,'FontSize',14)
xlabel('X','fontSize',14);
ylabel('Y','fontSize',14);
zlabel('Z','fontsize',14);
title('3D Parametric Equation Lily impeller','fontsize',14)
fh = figure(1);
set(fh, 'color', 'white');
```

Image it creates:
[image: Lily Image]

What I'm trying to model.

[image: Lily1]
[image: Lily2]

How can I change the equation to have the sides be pushed up more and to the right at a steeper angle like the Lily Impeller image?  The Left image is what I have the right Image is what I'm trying to get to.

**Note: I know the Z value is what changes this I'm just not sure what the correct values should be to change it to increase that "steepness angle".**

[image: Lily pushed]

Comment: play with the u and v values inside z (e.g. dividing both by 2 seems to have a close enough effect)

Comment: You can change z to form a logarithmic shape `z = -(u*3 + 5* (-log(x.^2 + y.^2)));`. See also [Dini's surface](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DinisSurface.html) and [here](https://help.geogebra.org/topic/making-3d-spirals-with-depth).